# Best way to load large amouts of data into datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am trying to load a lot of data into a datagrid which as you would expect takes a long time to load up.  This is due to the face that I am loading data from a COM object which I have wrapped up into .NET object with a custom enumerator.

I have looked into virtual loading the datagrid and it works alright but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing the same thing.

What I am after is a datagrid that shows a scroll bar for the whole amount of data but only loads the data for the first say 50 rows then after you scroll it loads the next 50 or so.

Does anyone know if this is possible, or if there is a control available that does this automatically?

Comment: Isn't paging an option ?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to load only a part of the data from the COM object? If so, load for example 100 rows, and save the rowcount. Then in the scroll event of the grid, use the FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex property to see if you are getting close to 100, and load some more rows, and increment the rowcount.

This does not however show a scrollbar for all loadable rows.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com) datagrid controls.